# Where can one find detailed information about stack operation in x86 processors

Tags: memory-management, assembly, x86

I am interested in the layout of an executable and dynamic memory allocation using stack and how the processor and kernel together manage the stack region, like during function calls and other scenarios of using stack based memory allocation. Also how stack overflow and other hazards associated with this model occur, are their other designs of code execution that are not stack based and don't have such issues. A video or an animation would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically (any processor, not just x86) there is one ram address space, and typically the program is in lower memory and grows upwards as you run.  Say your program is 0x1000 bytes and is loaded at 0x0000 then you do a malloc of 0x3000 bytes the address returned would be 0x1000 in this hypothetical situation and now the lower 0x4000 bytes are being actively used by the program. Additional mallocs continue to grow in this way.  Free()s do not necessary cause this consumption to go down, it depends on how the memory is managed and the programs mixture of malloc()s and free()s.

The stack though normally goes from the top down.  Say 0x10000 is the address the stack pointer starts at.  Say you have a function that has three 32 bit unsigned int variables, and no parameters are passed in, you need three stack locations to hold those variables (assuming no optimization has reduced that requirement) so upon entry of the function the stack pointer is reduced by 3*4 = 12 bytes, so the stack pointer is changed to 0xFFF4, one of your variables is at address 0xFFF4+0 one at 0xFFF4+4 and the third at 0xFFF4+8.  If that function calls another function then the stack pointer continues to move toward zero in memory.  And as you continue to malloc() your used program memory grows upward.  Unchecked they will collide, and the code needed to do that checking is cost prohibitive enough that it is rarely used.  This is why local variables are good for optimizing and a few other things but bad because stack consumption is often non-deterministic or at least the analysis is not done by the average programmer.

On ISAs (instruction set architectures) like x86 where there is a limited number of usable registers then functions often need to pass arguments on the stack as well.  The rules governing where and how things are passed and returned is defined and well understood by the compiler, this is not some random thing.  Anyway, in addition to leaving room for the local variables some of the arguments to the function are on the stack and sometimes the return value is on the stack.  In particular with x86, each function call causes the stack to grow downward, and functions calling functions makes that worse.  Think about what recursion can do to your stack.

What are your alternatives?  Use an instruction set with more registers with a function calling spec that uses more registers and less stack.  Use fewer arguments when calling functions.  Use fewer local variables.  Malloc less.  Use a good compiler with a good optimizer as well as help the optimizer by using easy to optimize habits when coding.

Realistically though, to have a generically useful processor for which you write generically useful programs you have to have a stack and the possibility that the stack overflows and/or collides with the heap.

Now the segmented memory model of the x86 as well as mmus in general give you the opportunity to keep the program memory and stack well away from each other.  Also protection mechanisms can be used that if either the heap or the stack venture outside their allocated space a protection fault occurs.  Still an oversight by the programmer but is easier to know what happened and debug it than the random side effects that occur when the stack grows down into program memory space.  Using a protection mechanism like this is much easier solution to help the programmer control the stack growth than building something into the code generated by the compiler to check for a collision on every function call and malloc.

Another pitfall which is often asked in job interviews is something along the lines of:

```
int * myfun ( int a )
{
   int i;

   i=a+7;
   return(&i);
}
```

This can take many forms, the thing to understand is that the variable i is temporarily allocated on the stack and is only allocated while the function is executing, when the function returns the stack pointer frees up the memory allocated for i and the next function called may very well clobber that memory.  So by returning the address to a variable stored on the stack is a bad idea.  Code that does something like this may run properly for weeks, months, years before being detected.

Now this is acceptable even on stack based cpus (the zylin zpu for example).

```
int myfun ( int a )
{
   int i;

   i=a+7;
   return(i);
}
```

Partly because there isnt much you can do other than use globals (yes this specific case does not require the additional variable i, but assume your code is complicated enough that you need that local return variable), the second is because in C, the calling code frees up its portion of the stack.  Meaning on an x86 for example if you call a function with two parameters on the stack, lets say two 4 byte ints, the calling code moves the stack pointer down by 8 and places those two parameters in that memory (sp+0 and sp+4), then when the function returns the calling code is the one that unallocates those two variables by adding 8 to the stack pointer.  So in the above code using i and returning i by value, the C calling convention for that processor knows where to get the return value, and once that value is captured the stack memory holding that value is no longer needed.   My understanding is that pascal, say borland turbo pascal for example the calee cleaned up the stack.  So the caller would put the two variables on the stack and the function being called would clean up the stack.  Not a bad idea as far as stack management goes, you can nest much deeper this way.  there are pros and cons to both approaches.

Comment: hmmm, you only have an assembly tag, did I completely misunderstand your question?